# Passing metadata and file to controller

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

using ASP.NET MVC and AJAX i'm trying to pass some data to the controller. How can i pass a zip file and some informations like a short description, category to the controller without using a model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point of model view controllers is that there is always a model somewhere.

On the model / controller side, just handle it like any other form submitted upload.

On the view side, start with something along the lines of 
http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/
and tweak it to suit your purposes.

http://cpratt.co/file-uploads-in-asp-net-mvc-with-view-models/ 
includes an example of upload plus other fields.

Comment: The problem is that i can't figure it out how to pass the file from view to the controller and also pass some other information stored in a model.

Comment: Maybe you need something like http://cpratt.co/file-uploads-in-asp-net-mvc-with-view-models/

Comment: Just what i need it. Thanks.